# Can´t get the current express session

Tags: node.js, session, express, mongoose, express-session

I want to set and retrieve the session from a current logged user, so I did something like this:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
  if (JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}") {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "corpo vazio" });
  }

  if (!req.body.email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "tem que especificar um email" });
  }

  if (!req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: "tem que especificar uma password" });
  }

  Loja.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, loja) {
    if (!loja) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "login invalido" });
    }
    if (loja.password != req.body.password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "password invalida" });
    }
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500);
    }
    // se tudo correr bem guarda a sessao do utilizador
    req.session.loja = loja;
    return res.send(req.session.loja);
  });
});
```

then to retrieve the session i do something like this:

```
router.get('/confirm-login',function(req,res){
  return res.send(req.session.loja);
});
```

tried it our, the first works well, it sends me a response with the full object that needs to be stored, but when I hit confirm-login at postman it send me an empty response :S, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write such a route you should first check the existence of `session` and stuff you've attached to it and send a proper response otherwise:

```
router.get('/confirm-login',function(req,res){
  if ( req.session && req.session.loja ) {
    res.send(req.session.loja);
  } else {
    res.status(401).send({ status: 'Unauthorized'});
  }
});
```

---

Postman chrome app can't handle cookies by itself. To work with cookies you should install a chrome extension called [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo/support?hl=en) (See [Documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/interceptor_cookies)).
So if you are using chrome app make sure you've got this extension installed and its on(enabled).
[image]

Comment: thank you, solved part of the problem, i get the session now, it has something to do with the cookie parser, now i have other problem how can i get the session when the user loged in?